# Assigning to a new list just the last object of another list - Python

Tags: python

OK, in Python I have list:

```
flowers = ["rose", "bougainvillea", "yucca", "marigold", "daylilly", "lilley of the valley"]
```

Now, I want to assign just the last object of list flowers to a new list called poisonous.

I tried:

```
poisonous=flowers[-1]
```

However this statement makes poisonous a string instead of a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  this instead

```
poisonous=flowers[-1:]
```

Demo:

```
>>> flowers = ["rose", "bougainvillea", "yucca", "marigold", "daylilly", "lilley of the valley"]
>>> 
>>> flowers[-1:]
['lilley of the valley']
```

Your issue was, you were indexing, which returns an object. Whereas, slicing would return a list.

Comment: Since it is not obvious how this works if you haven't seen it before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295

Comment: Looks good.  The colon is what is required to make it into a list then?

Comment: @user2461994 That is right. You needed a slice instead of the indexing .

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> poisonous=[flowers[-1],] #take the last element and put it in a list
>>> poisonous
['lilley of the valley']
>>> poisonous=flowers[-1] #take the last element, which is a string
>>> poisonous
'lilley of the valley'
>>> poisonous=flowers[-1:] #take a slice of the original list. The slice is also a list.
>>> poisonous
['lilley of the valley']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the object to be assigned in square bracket to make it a list assignment.

```
poisonous = [flowers[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

And, probably more useful:

```
flowers = [
    "rose", 
    "bougainvillea", 
    "poison oak",
    "yucca", 
    "marigold", 
    "daylily", 
    "lily of the valley",
]

snakes = [
    "king",
    "rattler",
]

poisonous = []

poisonous.append(flowers[-1])
poisonous.append(snakes[-1])

print poisonous

--output:--
['lily of the valley', 'rattler']
```